# Finding a simple graph such that its automorphism group equals the subgroup of $S_3$ generated by a 3-cycle

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, automorphism-group, permutation-cycles

I have found that the subgroup of $S_3$ generated by a 3-cycle is $\{e,(123),(132)\}$ where $e$ is the identity but I can't find any graphs that have this group as their automorphism group.

I am a little bit confused as one of the automorphisms is $(123)$, the graph should have $3$ vertices but every graph I have tried to draw with $3$ vertices has $(123)$ as one of their automorphisms, have also have different automorphisms such as $(1)(23)$ so they do not satisfy the requirement in the title.

Comment: I don't think they want you to find a graph whose automorphism group is the actual **permutation** group $\{(1),(1\ 2\ 3),(1\ 3\ 2)\}$; there is no such graph, unless you're talking about **directed** graphs. They just want a graph whose automorphism group is **isomorphic** to $\{(1),(1\ 2\ 3),(1\ 3\ 2)\}$. In other words, find a graph whose automorphism group is a cyclic group of order $3$, i.e., find a graph with exactly $3$ automorphisms.

Comment: It will have to have more then $3$ vertices. I think the smallest one has $9$ vertices.

Comment: I think you realized that a triangle graph doesn't work since it gives a dihedral group. A directed cycle of length $3$ is what we want, but unfortunately, we are not allowed directed edges. The trick is to replace edges in the triangle graph with a bigger pattern that implements a kind of directedness.

Comment: @mantaray, [This is a graph](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/1315) on nine vertices with exactly $3$ automorphisms.  Did you want this?

Comment: Hi, that was exactly it! As user14111 and caduk said they wanted the automorphism group to be isomorphic to  ${(1),(123),(132)}$ instead of being equal to it. Thank you all for your help!